# absolute position in yahoo mail

Tags: html, email, yahoo, email-templates

Any way to acchive absolute position in email template . I am trying faux position but in Yahoo mail max-height 0 gets converted to min height 0 .

```
  <td width="70%" style="" align="">
    <div height="0px" style="position:relative;margin-top:0px;
    min-height:0px;max-height:0px;">



<div style="margin-left:8% !important;position:relative !important;display:inline-block !important;margin-top:0px;">
```

```
</div>





                                                        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Faux absolute position](https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position) works well in Yahoo! Mail. Yahoo does convert `height` into `min-height`, but not `max-height`. The following example works well right now in Yahoo’s desktop webmail. (The “Hello World” div overlaps the lorem ipsum one.)

```html
<div style="max-height:0;">
    <div style="margin-left:8%;">⚠️ Hello World</div>
</div>
<p style="margin:0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, accusantium.</p>
```

Feel free to share your entire code if you still have a problem.

Comment: When you forward email it gets converted to min-height